# Do I need to unsubscribe a listener to stream that ends in Kefir?

Tags: kefir.js

I'm moving from BaconJS where this isn't an issue because you can just return `Bacon.noMore` in the subscriber to unsubscribe. In Kefir, unsubscribing is more boilerplate and so the natural question is---for streams that end, do you need to unsubscribe the listener (aka callback) or does Kefir handle that for you automagically?

```
const oneTimeStream = Kefir.constant('foo') // this ends after firing foo
const listener = function() { //... }

oneTimeStream.onValue(listener)
// do I need to unsubscribe #listener?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the library author, the answer is "No": https://github.com/rpominov/kefir/issues/182

> Yeah, you don't need to. All listeners automatically removed on end. Also when you subscribe to an ended stream it's a noop.
>
> Btw, because of that you can often avoid manual unsubscribing by limiting stream with take/takeWhile/takeUntilBy/etc.

```
stream.take(1).onValue(fn)
```